# Скроллинг со случайными координатами, и случайным временем, что ставить вместо x и y?

Tags: javascript

Скроллинг со случайными координатами,  что ставить вместо `x` и `y`?

Например, мы имеем автоматическую прокрутку:

```
function autoScrolling() {
  window.scrollToRandom();
}
```

Как быть со случайными координатами?

С обычными я разобрался сам сегодня, например:

```
function autoScrolling() {
  window.scrollBy(340,640);
}
```

Все четко работает, а вот как быть с этим?

```
function autoScrolling() {
  window.scrollToRandom();
}
```

Что в скобочки еще добавить?

---

И еще, вот вместо определенного времени, например:

```
setTimeout(autoScrolling,2000);
```

Как сделать случайное время?

```
setRandom();
```

Какие значения вводить в скобки? Я примерно понял, но со скроллингом случайные числа пока у меня еще не работают.

Comment: откуда вообще взяты эти методы? И зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 0):

1) случайное время почитайте и используйте https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

2) создаем кастомный метод

```
window.scrollToRandom = function(){
x = getRandomHeight();
y = getRandomWidth();
window.scrollBy(x,y);
}
```

создаем две функции для вычисления случайного x и y (высота и ширина отдельно) на основе Math.random() и с ограничением высоты или ширины странички. 
Вызываем в любое время и месте, после инциализации и страничка скачет